# Group Markers - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following Code for creating my markers:

```
var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value2["lat"], value2["lon"]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: siteLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png',
    title: value2["title"],
    zIndex: 4,
    html: value2["content"]
});
```

Now I want to group the markers from my map, that was created by

```
var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 10);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: centerMap,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMapsPreview'), myOptions);
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you find a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Maps API V3 you can now create a MarkerCluster for getting those markers together.

I don't have any working example but you can go to: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers
 to get more information about it.

And actually there are some examples over the web like this one here:
https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html

To use it, you will have something like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
var markers = [...]; // Create the markers you want to add and collect them into a array.
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: question was to group markers not cluster them. the need to group markers is important.

Comment: @Siddharth do you know how can I group the markers? I don't need clusters.